# Programmatically load webform edit page by SID

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I am trying to load an edit form like (drupal 7) : node/6/submission/72/edit into a custom page where I run the drupal_render_form

but I am not sure is this the same as node load form? can some one provide references on how to load webform submission edit page into a body of page.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by creating a custom module, with a custom page and inside the custom page I use the :

```
drupal_get_form
```

and it works perfect!